# Output file names are not known beforehand

Tags: snakemake

I have a folder where the `hdf5` files inputs are (matrices of `scRNAseq` raw `UMI` counts). There is a `python` script that loads them, splits them into multiple matrices, normalizes them, and saves as `csv` files. When the name pattern of the output files is known, things are easy, I know how to do that, but when one input (`hdf5` file) can produce various number of outputs (`csv` files) I am not sure how to approach the issue. Currently my `Snakemake` file relevant part looks the following way:

```
hdf5_files,=glob_wildcards('/main/{hdf5_file}.hdf5') 

rule all:
  input:
--->  expand('data_files/normalized/{hdf5_file}.csv', hdf5_file=hdf5_files)
    ...

rule normalization:
  input:
     script = 'python/normalize.py',
     path = '/main/{hdf5_file}.hdf5'
  output:
--->  path = 'data_files/normalized/{hdf5_file}.csv'
  shell:
     "python {input.script} -data {input.path} -path {output.path}"
```

Above I highlighted the `2` lines that I am not sure now how I should write. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using [flag files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#flag-files)? Or do you need the names for downstream processing too and can't use `glob` or specify a directory at that point?

Comment: The `rule normalization` processes, say, `2` `hdf5` files and outputs `10` `csv` ones into `data_files/normalized` folder. Then, I want to use `glob_wildcards` to read in these `10` `csv` files and move on.  Further rules are, of course, fully dependent on the `rule normalization` because it generates the input `csv` files. I am not sure how can I use `flag files`, but will try. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, if you need to process each of the resulting csv files independently downstream then there are no snakemake tricks that I know of that will help (I presume `glob_wildcards()` is run during rule parsing, so the CSV files won't be there yet). I suspect you'll want to run `normalization` from a wrapper script beforehand in that case, since then globbing will be certain to work as desired.

Comment: What do you mean from a `wrapper script`? Outside the pipeline, you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A (probably python) script that runs two Snakefiles when you call it, with appropriate options. Then you have the flexibility you need while maintaining the convenience of snakemake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you give an example of names of input files and output files of `normalize.py` ?

It seems to me that your case could be similar to the one described about the `dynamic` output:

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files

Here you would probably use it for the output of `normalization` and for the input of `all` (with a wildcard different from `hdf5_file`).

Disclaimer: I haven't had the opportunity to use this feature so far.

Comment: Sample name is `{hdf5_file}_{num}.hdf5`, where `num` is an integer.